# How to change the space between bars in geom_bar?

Tags: r, ggplot2, space, geom-bar

I have a bar plot with positive values on both sides. When I changed the width of the bars, the space between them became to large and doesn't look good. I tried to manipulate this with `position = position_dodge`, but it doesn't work. How can I reduce the spaces between the bars?

Here is the code (originally posted here [Stacked barplot crossing the x-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22236617/stacked-barplot-crossing-the-x-axis)) with my data:

```
Year <- factor(c("2003-2009","2003-2009","2003-2009","2003-2009","2003-2009","2009-2012",
              "2009-2012","2009-2012","2009-2012","2009-2012"))
Q <- c(.05,.25,.5,.75,.95)
Score <- c(6,6,4,3,1,23,20,19,24,32)
df <- data.frame(Year, Q, Score)

df <- transform(df, Score=ifelse(as.character(Year) %in% c("2003-2009"), -Score, Score))
df.split <- split(df, df$Score < 0)

ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(data=df.split[[1]],aes(x=Q, y=Score, fill=Year), stat="identity",width = 0.09)+
  geom_bar(data=df.split[[2]],aes(x=Q, y=Score, fill=Year), stat="identity",width = 0.09)+
  geom_hline(yintercept=0) +
  coord_flip()+
  scale_y_continuous(labels=abs,limits=c(-40,40))+ 
  theme_bw()+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(.05,.25,.5,.75,.95))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treating the `Q` variable as a factor will set the space between the bars equal. Normally, when you reduce the `width` of the bars, the space between the bars increases. However, you want narrow bars and small spaces between the bars. You can achieve this by changing the `height` of the saved image.

The code (I also changed the `width` of the bars & the scale of the y-axis a bit):

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(data=df.split[[1]],aes(x=as.factor(Q), y=Score, fill=Year), stat="identity", width = 0.4) +
  geom_bar(data=df.split[[2]],aes(x=as.factor(Q), y=Score, fill=Year), stat="identity", width = 0.4) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=abs,limits=c(-10,35)) + 
  theme_bw() +
  ggsave("myplot.png", width=8, height=2, dpi=300)
```

The result:

[image]

Note that I also deleted the `scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(.05,.25,.5,.75,.95))` part of the plotting code as this will give an error when treating `Q` as a factor variable.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions, but I've been wondering how to decrease spaces without changing the width of the bars.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want narrow bars and small spaces between the bars. I updated my answer. Does this give you the desired result?

Comment: Thank you. I've also experimented with "scale_x_discrete (expand = C (0,1.5))" at the end of the code. It also reduce spaces between the bars, but left too much below the lowest and above the highest bar.