# How can I change bar distance using R ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, width, bar-chart

I am plotting a bar plot with ggplot2. I want the bar width is very small,but the distance between the bars is very large, like the picture, how can I change the distance?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It’s easier to help if you make your question reproducible: include a minimal dataset in the form of an object for example if a data frame as df <- data.frame(…) where … is your variables and values or use dput(head(df)). Include the code you have tried. These links should be of help: [mre] and [ask]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ggplot2 : How to reduce the width AND the space between bars with geom\_bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50077342/ggplot2-how-to-reduce-the-width-and-the-space-between-bars-with-geom-bar)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example `ggplot(data = df, aes(x=X, y=Y, fill=F)) + geom_bar(width = 0.5, position = position_dodge(width = 0.8))`

`position_dodge(width = 0.8)` is for the space between the bars. `width = 0.5` is an example for the withd of the bar itself.

Let me know if it worked :)

Comment: No,this is not what i want.what i want is that  the X -axis xticks is can be change by set specific number so that the space between bars is very larger or smaller.Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

This question has been aswered at [ggplot2 : How to reduce the width AND the space between bars with geom_bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50077342/ggplot2-how-to-reduce-the-width-and-the-space-between-bars-with-geom-bar)

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(data = iris,
       mapping = aes(x = Species, 
                     y = Sepal.Length))+
  geom_col(width = .5)+
  theme(aspect.ratio = 3/2)
```

Without aspect ratio code:
[image]

With aspect ratio code:
[image]